# Mongoose populate subdocument returns null

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to populate a query with mongoose, using the "populate" method. I'm using the most recent/stable version of mongoose. The relevant parts of my schema are defined as shown below. The problem is that when I try to populate `const sessions = await Session.find().populate({ path: "coach", select: "name email" })`, I always get `"coach": null`.

I expected it to simply return the sessions that match my query together with the coach (user) object. What am I doing wrong here?

**UserSchema**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "email is required"],
    unique: [true, "email must be unique"],
    match: [/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/, "Invalid email"]
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "name is required"]
  },
  (....)
});

export const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

**SessionSchema**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const SessionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  coach: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
  location: {
    street: { type: String }
  },
  (......)
});

export const Session = mongoose.model('Session', SessionSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the coach type should be the following (`Schema.Types` seems to be missing):

```
  coach: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found it. Sorry, guys. The code is ok. The problem was that I was seeding my DB with entries that had a "id" property, not a "_id" property. So, the "id" was not getting saved properly and thus the response was actually `null`.